# ESXi 6.5 host does not respond to direct web access after boot (HTML5 client not accessible)

Tags: vmware-esxi, server-setup

I have a simple ESXi (all default) free install in a home lab network that only has the host, a switch (with builtin DHCP) and a laptop. The DHCP provides both the laptop and ESXi host with IP as follows:

`ESXi host (192.168.1.2) -------------> switch
                laptop (192.168.1.3) ----^`

(Note that I have also tried sidestepping the DHCP server and setting static IPs for all hosts but I am not able to connect)

The web client and SSH are only accessible in the pre-boot period before the host becomes completely functional, with the loading screen on the DCUI console still visible). However, as soon as the boot finishes the connections drop and the server is not accessible from my laptop (192.168.1.3). Moreover, trying to ping form the host to my laptop (using the network test and the shell) all packets are dropped before reaching the switch.

I have tried to disable the firewall (`esxcli network firewall set --enabled false` and `esxcli network firewall set --default-access true`) but still was not able to connect.

Comment: Did you set a gateway? and why in dhcp the host ?

Comment: I only used dhcp just because that was the default after trying multiple times with the static setup which didn't work, so I assumed I might was misconfigured (even though it looked completely fine). I will try again now, but I highly doubt it will work. EDIT: it does not work with static either, I just tried again.

Comment: What's the actual real problem you're trying to solve? Not being able to ping doesn't describe a problem that has any relevance in the context of your question. I can't ping a lot of my machines, because inbound ICMP isn't enabled, and I could care less if I can ping them or not. What I do care about is reaching the actual services that those machines offer.

Comment: My problem is that the web interface for managing the server is not accessible, neither is the SSH client (when enabled). I _only_ mean ping as an example. Maybe that's not clear in my question (I'll clarify it).

Comment: OK, describe those problems in your question. People aren't going to care whether you can ping or not. Not being able to access the host via HTTP/S and SSH is a real problem that people can focus on.

Comment: No offense, but your description of your setup is not clear at all and I can't wrap my head around whatever you are trying to do. You really need to redo this question. Be SPECIFIC, and clarify what and how things are physically hooked up, and use the right terminology. A GATEWAY is a router capable of allowing you to communicate with the outside world beyond your local network - "switch + DHCP with no internet access" makes no sense. Accessing from "beyond the gateway" requires more specific information about routing tables, network addressing, and possibly port forwarding.

Comment: It is technically a gateway with the WAN port disabled, so I wasn't sure if that changes anything. Anyway I rewrote the question. (edit: is the `lspci` useful, I can add it if needed)

Comment: Much better. It is now understandable. Although, being able to ping your laptop is not a good test. Your laptop might not be pingable. You are trying to connect from laptop to host, so pinging the host from the laptop would be more significant. Have you verified the firewall is disabled `network firewall get` and checked the network interface status with `network ip interface ipv4 get`  `network ip get` and `network ip interface list` after boot? The interface may go down if it is in conflict in some way.

Comment: I have the firewall on my laptop disable and ping to my laptop works as I have checked that from other hosts. I only ping to my laptop to make sure that traffic passes both ways. I have tried with the firewall enabled and disabled. I have checked the interfaces but nothing seems off. Is there something specific I should look out for?

Comment: Can you show us what the full IP/subnet mask/Gateway info is for both your ESXi host and laptop?

Comment: laptop: 192.168.1.3;
ESXi: 192.168.1.2;
gateway for both 192.168.1.1 (but not really important as there is no WAN/switch only). The thing that I don't get is that is works for a few seconds after boot but then stops responding.

Comment: What about subnet mask? You said there was a switch in the network? Is it a dumb switch or layer 2/layer 2+? Have you tried restarting the management service on the ESXi host? You said you tried setting static IPs for all hosts? How many hosts do you have?

Comment: I have use a /24 subnet with both a managed and a dumb switches and have restarted the network management tools and the host multiple times to no avail. While testing I only had the ESXi host + my laptop (+ sometimes a dhcp server), so total 2 hosts when going static. I suspect that it might be a problem with the Intel drivers.

Comment: In the DCUI, what are the results of the Test Management Network?

Comment: It fails, I have also tried directly from shell as well.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot or more information about how it failed? The more information the better.

Comment: I will update with logs and other data an soon I have more time to play with my server again (it is for a home test lab).

Comment: It troubles me what you are saying about > The web client and SSH are only accessible in the pre-boot period Web Service is usually the last thing to come up and you have to have previously enabled SSH on the host as it is not enabled by default.
Check your virtual Switch/Network configuration and try different modes (Bridged, NAT) as this seems to me as a networking issue.